# How to make a correct for loop with multiple conditions

Tags: python

I am making a game and 'on key down' it moves the character (self) down..

In the code below what I am trying to do is when a collision is detected re order the widgets depending on whether the collision occurs walking into a building from the bottom (in which case the character would be visible in front of it) or from the top (the building would be visible in front of the character)

The problem is that the code below is removing and readding the building widget.  I have tinkered with this statement for about an hour and no matter what I do, the first if statement is always true, even if I change the direction of the > to <, it's still true.
What am I doing wrong here?  I am hoping it is just a simple error in my for loop related to the building height or something.

```
elif keycode[1] == 'down':
```

## if character walks down and overlaps the building, place the building in front of the character

```
    if any(self.collide_widget(i) and self.y>(i.y+i.height) for i in listofwidgets):
        gamelayout.remove_widget(building)
        gamelayout.add_widget(building)
```

## if character has already walked up and collided with building, walking down should remove and re add hero widget so that it stays in front of building.

```
    elif any(self.collide_widget(i) and self.y<(i.y+i.height) for i in listofwidgets):
        gamelayout.remove_widget(hero)
        gamelayout.add_widget(hero)
```

Comment: The `elif` is not "taking precedence". Quite clearly, the `if` condition is evaluating to `False`. Why that is the case -- and indeed why you think it *shouldn't* be the case -- is unclear.

Comment: Can you make `self.collide_widget(i)` fail in a test, for any widget *i* constructed to not even touch on the character?  What is the type of `y` ?

Comment: If you use [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html), you can set a breakpoint right at your `if` statement, and then print out the values of all your local variables `i`, `i.height`, `collide_widget(i)` and so on.